# what is the theoretical benchmark upon which to make select the artifical network to predicting data?

Tags: performance, validation, testing, neural-network, mse

I have trained neural networks for 50 times(training) now I am not sure which network (from 50nets) I should choose to predict my data?Among MSE(mean square error) of network or R-squred or validation performance or test performance?....Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have a training data, which you actually use to build a predictive model (so you need network for some actual application, and not for research purposes) then you should just have split with two subsets: training and validation, nothing else. Thus when you run your 50 trainings (over k-fold CV or random splits) you are supposed to use it to find out what set of hyperparameters is the best. And you select **hyperparameters** which lead to the best **mean** score over these 50 splits. Then you **retrain** your model on the whole dataset with these hyperparameters. Similarly - if you want to select between K algorithms, you use each of them to approximate their generalization capabilities, select the one with biggest **mean** score, and retrain this particular model on the whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.I used Matlab and based on dividrand 3sets of data for train/test/validation instead of K-fold method.So now I have 50 of  MSE(mean square error) of network and R-squred and validation performance and test performance but from one net to another these criteria are different so I am not sure which network is best for predicting data

Comment: Again - you do not need triple split. Splitting is used to fit additional hyperparameters (for neuron Network this includes stopping criteria). Again- you do not Delecta a Network but set of parameters and you use them to train a **single** Network, which is your finał model

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to take your advice one more question is what is hyperparameters?number of hidden neuron?Thanks again

Comment: Hyperparameters are all things you fix by your own, things that are not trained. For NN these include: Network structure (number of layers, number of units in each layer, activation function, etc.), optimizer params (optimization algorithm, learning rate, momentum, etc.), cost params (regularization Type and strength etc.)